# how to get only specific css selectors being used by web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider a web-page

```
<html>
<head> 
  <p class="header"></p>
</head>
<body class="main">
</body>
</html>
```

and my css file,

```
.header{}
.main{}
.footer{}
```

I'd like to know which css selectors are being used, so i can delete the rest from my stylesheet.Here, I can delete `.footer`

is this possible?

Comment: You may wanna check out FF plugins like Dust-Me

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, you can use the built-in tool:
http://meeech.amihod.com/very-useful-find-unused-css-rules-with-google/

For Firefox, you can use a plugin like DustMe:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

But keep in mind that a selector might not be used on the current page, but it may be used on other pages.